# How to connect to a machine on another network with Files’ “Connect to Server”

Tags: iphone, wifi, files.app

I just discovered this feature on my iPhone. I managed to connect to my Mac and another Windows computer when I’m connected to the same wifi. Is it possible to setup a connection when I’m using cellular data or I’m connected to another wifi? If so, how? I’ve searched the web far and wide but I nothing came up. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes… but…**
In theory you can connect to any server you have the address for - but in practise getting through to your own home network requires a lot of additional work.

You first need to know your home public IP address, which may change on a regular basis at the whim of your ISP, or may be unreachable if it is behind a [CGNAT (Carrier-grade Network Address Translation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) structure.

Once past this hurdle, you then need to set up [port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router, to send the correct packets to the designated in-house computer. This comes with its own set of security issues you need to be prepared for, as it essentially opens up a part of your home computer's system to direct access from the internet.

All in all, unless you are very invested in achieving this - it's simpler to say "it's not possible".
Use iCloud or DropBox etc. instead.
Structures such as iCloud & DropBox work by connecting to a central offsite 'cloud' location accessible from anywhere in the world, with the correct credentials. They don't rely on trying to 'punch a hole' in your existing home network's security.

Comment: This is of course what Back To My Mac used to do, though it was somewhat unreliable. Resilio Sync continues to sync my laptop and desktop when I'm on the road, without any port config on my router. One would have thought that it ought to be possible, what with certificates and identities and what-have-you.

Comment: Back to My Mac relied on consumer-standard commands (UPnP & NAT-PMP) the router would (in theory) accept, basically punching the hole from the inside not the outside. idk whether it was reliability or security that finally made them abandon it.

Comment: I understand, thank you so much for the explanation